# Problem in loading images...iPhone xcode

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, sprite

I want to animates images in such a way that when user click on button 2 so 6 images splash 1 by 1 on the screen. The problem is that image animation is too much slow. Let suppose i am using 6 buttons, Each button have 6 images what will i do in order to achieve fast feedback when click on the button.

Comment: increase the animation.duration;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to decrease animation duration..
like if i want my animation duration for 0.4 seconds then write [animation setDuration:0.4f];

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Quartz](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101) built-in library for image manipulation.